# auto completion unix function prototype

Tags: c, visual-studio, ide

I was using VS for C programming and currently decided to work on a project which needs socket programming (so I decided to use a unix operating system).

The problem is in VS there was a property to see functions prototypes by writing down some characters of them or seeing what variables you have in a structure.

I wanted to see if there is another IDE which has this property cause I tried Codeblocks and it seems Codeblocks doesn't support them.

Sorry for asking here cause even I don't know what these properties called maybe something like auto completion function prototype or ...

Comment: The term you are looking for is Visual Studios [IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx) feature, but even googling for `C IDE auto completion` yields many results such as [CodeLite](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/CodeCompletion) or [this review](https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-ide-editors-source-code-editors/) of good C IDE's.

Comment: Vim must have this feature. At least available through extension.

Comment: Are you really using Unix and not Linux? Otherwise one option might be [Linux development with C++ in Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/11/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: unfortunately I tried CodeLite but it's auto completion is sucks.

Comment: I also tried to use Linux development of VS but cannot understand SSH and how it works, still don't check Vim but hope the last one work. thanks for help guys : )